# Switching languages in front-end, causes broken design and scripts not loading

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.3.x, templates, language

I installed a multilingual (English / Arabic ) Joomla site successfully and I set English language to be the default one.
When I'm on the English version the page is displayed correctly but when I'm switching the language to the Arabic version the design is broken.

After some investigation with the page's source code, I found out that the script files are not loaded.
Can anyone give any help regarding this issue, I tried to edit the template files but no luck.

Thanx.

Comment: for example jquery file is not loaded, also I checked from the designer that the template is multilingual template

Comment: Please enable error reporting and see if there are any php errors, and can you post a link to your site?

Comment: No loaded at all or the path is incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx @FFrewin after I enabled the error reporting I found that this module causing the error "K2 News Category" as it's very old module and i'm using the latest version of joomla, k2, minik2 after disabling it the translated page worked correctly, I'm going to search for a new module to replace the old one.

Thanx,

Answer (score 0):

As a general advise for such kind of issues, when there is a broken layout/design, scripts are missing etc:

> Remember to enable Error Reporting

In many cases, there can be a php error caused by an extension or any other kind of code anywhere in the system, that might prevent the proper operation of the page/site.

For example if a Fatal Error occurs, then the page won't be able to load at full, if at all - and of course missing CSS or JS would be a normal symptom (not the cause), since the code that generates them, won't be able to run at all.